What string can be used in JPQL order by to cause SQL injection?
Consider code similar to this:
String orderBy = getParameter("orderBy");
String orderDir = getOrderDir(); // returns "asc" or "desc"
String query = "select u from User u order by u." + orderBy + " " + orderDir;

The query is used as a JPA query (NOT as a native query).
Considering the restrictions of JPQL what value could be used for parameter orderBy to cause any actual harm and not just exception caused by faulty query?
JPQL does not allow union or comments (--) so I do not know how / if one could cause any harm in the system.
I do understand that this needs to be fixed, but I am wondering how dangerous this vulnerability actually is.

Depending on the implementation of JPA, you may be able to use UNION. For example in EclipseLink 2.4: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#UNION
If you are using an implementation that doesn't allow UNION, a query could cause mischief if it involves a subquery.
For example, here's a query that pauses for an hour per row:
... from User order by (select sleep(3600)) asc;

This doesn't damage your database per se, but it could be a denial of service attack.
SQL injection risk can also be unintentional. It isn't just malicious attackers you have to worry about. Some issues are caused by honest mistakes by users.
For example, what if a user enters "the column" as their sorting argument?
... from User order by the column asc;

This is just an error, not an attack that damages your database. But it's a at least embarrassing and unprofessional for your website to have a fatal SQL error due to user input of any kind, isn't it?

Re your comment and edited query:
You changed the query to try to ensure the order by uses only a qualified column name, but the attacker could still inject more syntax:
... from User order by u.id, (select sleep(3600)) asc;
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            injected content


Hi. Thank you for the answer. I know this is an error, I need to identify the severity of potential harm this can do within the system. Also, I have updated the original query a bit (adding additional syntax that decreases potential options).
Can you still find any string that could be used that does not simply cause an exception for faulty query?

@Macok why are you looking for a work-a-round when best practice is to fix your query so questions like this are irrelevant? -- Personally I wouldn't want to ask a question as to "how I can be defeated" when the solution is a smarter query that makes "defeat" something you never have to think about

@ViaTech Nobody is looking for a workaround. I literally stayed in the question that I know this needs to be fixed. Two things however: 1) I want to make sure my knowledge of JPQL is adequate. I cannot think of any harmful way, but if there are I want to know about it. 2) Fixing a bug is easy. Prioritising which bugs should get fixed ASAP in an old legacy system with thousands of bugs, loopholes, vulnerabilities isn't. But ultimately, I want to increase my knowledge and make sure I'm not missing anything.
